# Rewrite loop as a mapcar

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

Looking at [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-building-a-unit-test-framework.html), we're looking at a simple automated unit test framework. We're trying to write a macro to be used as such:

```
(check (= (+ 1 2) 3) (= (- 1 4) 9))
```

This should expand to something using a previously defined function `report-result`. The suggested implementation is:

```
(defmacro check (&body forms)
  `(progn
     ,@(loop for f in forms collect `(report-result ,f ',f))))
```

However, that expansion seems rather procedural to me. I wanted to replace the `loop` with a `mapcar` to expand to something like this:

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (form) (report-result form 'form)) (list form-1 ... form-n))
```

However, I'm clearly lacking the macro-writing skills to do so. Can someone come up with one such macro?

In case it's relevant, this is the definition of `report-result`:

```
(defun report-result (result form)
  (format t "~:[FAIL~;pass~] ... ~a~%" result form))
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What to do you want to do? Do you want to replace `LOOP` with `MAPCAR`in the macro or should the expanded code contain a `MAPCAR`?

Comment: Well, honestly, it hadn't occurred to me that both forms were possible. @amalloy's answer provides a possible solution for the former. I was originally trying to write something so that `mapcar` occured in the expanded code. Is that also possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed fairly simple: you just place the `collect` expression into the body of your `mapcar`:

```
(defmacro check (&body forms)
  `(progn
    ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (form)
                  `(report-result ,form ',form))
              forms)))
```

You don't really need to know anything about the "macro-y" stuff that's going on, in order to do the replacement you want, which is simply replacing a `loop` with some other equivalent expression: it will work just as well in a macro context as it would outside.

If you want to expand to a `mapcar` you can, but there's no real reason to do so, since the list's size is known at compile time. Here's what that would look like:

```
(defmacro check (&body forms)
  `(let ((results (list ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (form)
                                      `(list ,form ',form))
                                  forms))))
     (mapcar #'(lambda (result)
                 (report-result (car result) (cadr result)))
             results)))
```

Which expands like so

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(check (+ 1 2) (* 2 3)))
(let ((results (list (list (+ 1 2) '(+ 1 2))
                     (list (* 2 3) '(* 2 3)))))
  (mapcar #'(lambda (result) (report-result (car result) (cadr result)))
          results))
```

Which as you can see is rather awkward: the macro already has the forms like `(+ 1 2)` available to it, but in order to preserve them to runtime for the mapcar lambda to see, you have to emit the input form twice. And you have to produce the whole list to map over, rather than just producing a list that's "finished" to begin with. Additionally, this produces a list as output, and requires having all the inputs and outputs in memory at once: the original macro with `progn` produced the inputs and outputs one at a time, and discarded them when finished.

Comment: Very simple indeed! I was trying to write something that would expand to a `mapcar` and was having trouble with escaping/unescaping lists. You wouldn't have any such solution available now, would you? :)

Comment: You can't do that (at least, not usefully). There's no point expanding to (mapcar f (list ...)) instead of just (list (f a) (f b)). Since the list has to be a known, fixed size at compile time, there's no need/reason to map over it at runtime instead of compile time. But, I guess I can include a "non-useful" version to demonstrate what I mean: I'll edit the answer shortly.